# Did all the spies stay together throughout the entire mission?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-shelach, meraglim-spies

In viewing Rash"i on [Bemidbar 13:21-22](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39995&st=&pgnum=91), it seems that the Torah lists things out of order unless it is describing "general" first and then "specifics".

In other words - in reading Rash"i on verse 21, he says that they started in the southeast corner of the land, and returned going south along the western border by the sea (Mediterranean).

Verse 22 says "They went up the Negev and **he** came to Chevron."

Since Moshe said "Go up the Negev and climb the mountain," (verse 17) I'm inferring that this is how the spies started their travels. If I infer correctly, it seems that at some point while travelling north, Calev separated (see Rash"i on verse 22) separated from the rest of the group, and he went to Chevron.

OK - then what? Did he rejoin them? Did the rest of them continue travelling northward and eventually Calev caught up, or did they wait for him to return from Chevron? And, in general, do we know if all the other tribe leaders stayed together during the whole mission, or did they split up (besides Calev) along the way, and then rejoined somewhere else?

Comment: Notably, the other spies didn’t know what Kalev was up to; wouldn’t you think it’s odd if he broke off like that, and he was the only one who broke off like that, and nobody thought anything was up?

Comment: @DonielF Not necessarily. Rash"i explains that he went there to pray at *kever avot*. It's possible that he may have told them why he was going to Chevron, and they didn't think anything of it, either way. Perhaps, they just weren't interested in joining him.